# Ubuntu os hang permanently after inserting USB/SD card

Tags: usb, mount, 22.04, sd-card

Currently I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on virtual machine VMware workstation 9. The operating system is working fine, but if I insert SD card or USB the system hangs completely. I didn't find any solution in internet. Before inserting USB I checked the following command s:

```
lspci -vv -s 02:00.2
> USB controller VMware usb2 EHCI controller
lshw -C USB
> No info
lsusb 
> VMware Inc. virtual USB hub
```

In /media directory there is no folder for USB
/etc/fstab has no entry for USB too.
Please let me know the possible solutions.

Comment: Are the SD card and the USB stick correctly recognized and working in the host OS? If so how exactly are you trying to use them in the VM?

Comment: On my host PC windows 10 USB/ SD card recognize but in virtual machine if I plug it, system hang permanently.  Simply plugging USB/SD card on host PC then VMware> vm>removable device>(USB/SD card) connect

Comment: I suggest you run the Windows error correction tools in Windows for the external media, just in case.

Comment: If not that then probably the hypervisor (VMWare) is to blame. It seems to be a very old version from a decade ago, very likely NOT even compatible with Windows 10. And in any case this isn't really an Ubuntu question so you may want to ask at superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

My VMware version has no feature for USB. Maybe it can be license issue or something that I don't know. Normally there should be an option on VMware workstation vm>preference>USB. In my case this is missing. Solution: oracle vm virtualbox has this USB option and working fine